# Can not get data by ObjectId from MongoDB using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a `PersonalAccount` type as

```
type PersonalAccount struct {
        ID        bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
}
```

then I get a marshaled `PersonalAccount` through an HTTP request, and the data is unmarshaled successfully and when I check the ID type.
It is a `bson.ObjecID`

The problem is when I try the code below:

```
var m PersonalAccount = unmarshaledAccount
mgo.DB("dbname").C("colname").FindId(m.ID)
```

It returns an error that says it is not found.

I have also tried:

```
var m PersonalAccount = unmarshaledAccount
mgo.DB("dbname").C("colname").Find(bson.M{"_id": m.ID})
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
c.FindId(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex("56bdd27ecfa93bfe3d35047d")})
```

may be it will solve your problem